# Do I need the web.config file in the craft root directory?

Tags: config

I'm working off of a linux machine (Apache) I don't use the web.config that's found in `/public/web.config`. I will use the `.htaccess` file.

I am curious if I can remove the `web.config` file from `/craft/` since I am not in a windows environment. I have been removing it, but not sure if that's exactly a great idea...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're not specifically running IIS on Windows, then you can safely remove it.

Comment: That's what I figured - but thought I better ask for sure. Thanks Brad!